# Hosting Perforce server on internet?

Tags: version-control, perforce, server, p4v

I am configuring my system (OSX) as a perforce server for sharing my project work with my coding partner. I want to host my server on the internet so that he will able to connect to my system. I am able to configure through [this](http://www.perforce.com/documentation/tenminute-test-drive-mac) guide.Working like charm on my local host.

Maybe i am not getting something.

Please guide me to find an address or what procedure I have to do extra for making my system available to my partner .
I am very bad in UNIX terminal command
i tried these links but no answer worked for me . 
[Perforce with dynamic ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354160/perforce-with-dynamic-ip)

[Online Perforce Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397642/online-perforce-repositories)

Some questions

*Is there any need for static IP .*

*How i make my system available to partner over internet?*

This is my p4 info.

```
User name: aadi
Client name: aadi-MacBook-Air
Client host: aadi-MacBook-Air.local
Client unknown.
Current directory: /Users/aadi
Client address: 127.0.0.1:50596
Server address: localhost:1666
Server root: .
Server date: 2014/11/18 01:58:14 +0530 IST
Server uptime: 00:00:10
Server version: P4D/DARWIN90U/2011.1/747877 (2013/11/21)
Server license: none
Case Handling: insensitive
```

Comment: This is a network configuration question and is not specific to Perforce.  You need to learn about port forwarding, firewall configuration, possibly dynamic DNS, etc.  [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) would be a better place to ask this.  Actually, this is not hard.  You don't need to be an IT guru to do this, so asking at [Super User](https://superuser.com) would be a good option as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you need a static IP, so long as your partner can connect to you using your dynamic IP.

Your server has to listen on an IP address which is accessible by your partner, so "localhost:1666" will not work, because 'localhost' means to only accept connections from your own machine.

If your machine, was, say 192.168.1.101, then you'd like to see something like:

```
Server address: 192.168.1.101:1666
```

Which you should be able to accomplish by starting your server as 'p4d -p 192.168.1.101:1666'.

You can also try starting your server at 'p4d -p 1666' and see if it will listen on an address that is accessible by your partner's machine. It should, but occasionally there are problems if the IP address is not explicitly specified. If you explicitly specify your machine's IP address, and it is a dynamic IP, then you will have to stop and restart your server on the correct IP address each time your machine's IP address changes, which is rather an annoyance (and is avoided if you can in fact deploy a static IP).

All this business about static vs dynamic IP addresses should go away if your dynamic IP assignment mechanism is well-integrated with your organization's DNS infrastructure, so that your partner can use the hostname of your computer rather than the IP address.

Lastly, don't forget to check your OS X firewall: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642

Comment: Thanks for quick answer maybe i am not able to explain my question i have update my question. My question is to get access from other system from another city not on same network .

Comment: When i am trying to run p4d -p my.public.ip.ex:1666 i am getting [this](http://pastebin.com/A7NKSMWy) error, my firewall is turned off. And i am able to ping to my public ip address.

Comment: and yes what you said in answer is working on local networks. but not on public ip . One thing more out of this if i started server p4d -p 192.168.1.101:1666 then p4 admin stop is not working .any idea

Comment: Try just "p4d -p 1666" as Bryan suggested and it should listen on all available interfaces.

Is the client from another city able to ping your machine, access other services on it, etc?

Comment: @SamStafford I tired doing "p4d -p 1666" My client is able to ping to my machine. But not able to connect to my perforce server.

Comment: Another debugging strategy might be to see if you're able to run other services on this machine and access them remotely, e.g. a web server or a telnet server.  This still feels like a firewall issue (not necessarily on your local machine -- might be at the router that connects you to the outside).